# Forcing a Textblock in WPF to use all available vertical space and wrap its content

Tags: wpf, xaml, viewbox

I have a simple `Grid` with an `Image` on the left side and a `TextBlock` on the right, each contained by a `ViewBox` to handle scaling. The `ViewBox.Height` containing the `TextBlock` is bound to `Image.ActualHeight`. Here is what I get:

[image: What I have]

But what I actually want to achieve is that `TextBlock.FontSize` is automatically adjusted, so that all available vertical space is used and its content wraps. So it should rather look about like that:

[image: What I want]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717999/textblock-text-doesnt-wrap-when-placed-inside-a-viewbox

Comment: You could also make a relation between the FontSize and image height in code behind, so it actually fits the fontsize into the block during startup